# Cannot ping Ubuntu server by hostname

Tags: ping, hostname

I know this is already asked but I can't find a clear answer. I put a new Ubuntu server in my LAN and I can't ping it but the hostname. I don't want to edit all my LAN windows hosts's file   (+40 pcs) and add the entry. Perhaps I have another Ubuntu server and I can ping it by hostname without change anything.

All servers and client are using another internal DNS server based on an old redhat installation.

The hostname in the server that I can't ping is setted. What I have to do/check?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've got two options, of which you can do either or both:

- Install Samba (apt-get install samba) and activate the nmbd component, this will make the Ubuntu server answer broadcast NetBIOS name requests from Windows clients without further configuration.
- Add a record to your DNS server. You mentioned the DNS server is RedHat EL 4 so will quite likely be running ISC Bind. The configuration is in `/etc/named` and RedHat compatible manuals are still available here: http://www.centos.org/docs/4/html/rhel-rg-en-4/ch-bind.html

Edit: The second of these is preferable, you shouldn't rely on NetBIOS to do name resolution for you.

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a try. I think the difference between the 2 ubuntu servers is that the pingable one has samba installed (!) the other one nope. You win!

Comment: sorry, can you help me how to add a entry in the named file? I don't figure out how to add only one simple lan ip with the hostname:\

Answer (score 1):

Add an entry into DNS on your domain controller in forward lookup zones for the Ubuntu machine, this is what I normally do.

Comment: how to do that? The DNS server is on red hat 4 I think

Answer (score 0):

hostname.local should work, and if not, refer to [Ubuntu Zeroconf guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToZeroconf).

Comment: tried. didn't work:(. I'm pinging from windows machine

Comment: So the avahi-daemon is running but it's the same?

Comment: no avahi daemon is running on any servers

Answer (score 0):

See this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/516533

1. `sudo apt-get install winbind`
2. `sudo apt-get install libnss-winbind`
3. `sudo gedit /etc/nsswitch.conf and append "wins" after "files"`

   `hosts:          files wins mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns`

`ping WinComputer` shoud work from your ubuntu machine.

And from WinComputer you should be able to `ping UbuntuComp`